# Outlook 2003/2007/2010—Message Flagging

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2003

I have an Exchange account set up as an additional account for several different users: it's used as a collection point for engineering submissions from our contractors. Our users access the account to print, log, distribute, and archive the incoming and outgoing emails, and they indicate what they've done using colored flags. It's working very well for those of us using Outlook 2003 and 2007, but recently one of the players was randomly upgraded to 2010. Guess where I'm headed with this?

So the problem is, 2010 offers only red-flagging and colored categories, and 2003 cannot (I think) accommodate 2010's system of colored categories.  2003's colored flags actually DO show up in 2010, but can't be changed, and obviously, new 2010 flags only come in stunning shades of red. Since colored flags aren't going to work uphill for us, anybody know a way to categorize something in 2010 that can be read downhill in 2003? I work at an LGA (large government agency), so upgrades for those of us using 2003/2007 will come slowly, if at all, given the current state of funding.